# Testing Spring - REST API without mock

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit, cucumber-jvm

How does one invoke methods in a rest service that is not written in spring or java (its wcf rest service) using JUnit & Spring?

Note: I want to do HTTP-GET so mocking is not the case here.

Does Spring let me use `restTemplate.getForObject(..)` from JUnit? Cucumber?

---

So far I have a client written using Spring:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    private static final String SERVICE_URL="http://localhost:12345/PrivilegesService/IsAlive";


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
        return args -> {
            boolean response = restTemplate.getForObject(SERVICE_URL, boolean.class);
            log.info("response: "+ response); // print : true
        };
    }
}
```

I want my tests look :

```
public class StepDefinitions {

    @When("^application is up$")
    public void the_client_issues_GET_version(){

    }
    @Then("^the server should be running$")
    public void the_client_receives_status_code_of()  {
        boolean response = restTemplate.getForObject(SERVICE_URL, boolean.class);
        AssertTrue(true,response);
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it wouldn't allow use of RestTemplate in Junit? Of course it allows. More over REST is based on HTTP, so it doesn't matter what framework is used to write a REST service. As long as it is  a REST service, you should be able to call it

Comment: Thanks, It's working! Please write it as an answer.

Comment: <@Stav> Done. You wanna accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestTemplate works in Junit as well. It doesn't matter if its a source code or test code.
 REST is based on HTTP, so it doesn't matter what framework is used to write a REST service. As long as it is a REST service, you should be able to call it